# How to know what initial commands being executed right after a SSH login?

Tags: bash, ssh

I was provided a tool to do a SSH to a remote host.  The remote host is a new docker to be created.  I was trying to understand if there are commands being executed right after the SSH (i.e. probably using `ssh -t <some commands>`).

It seems like the `.bash_history` does not include those cmds.  In such case, what else can I do to figure out what cmds being executed right after my login?  Thank you.

Comment: Look at the configuration files that your login shell will source.

Answer (score 0):

To find out the actual commands that are executed, you could add "set -v" or "set -x" to the shell initialization file(s) on the system you are ssh-ing to.

See `man bash` (the "INVOCATION" section) to find out which files will executed so that you can figure out which file to add the "set" command to.

You will probably want to do that temporarily ... because the output is verbose.

Another approach would be to configure sshd to set the logging level to DEBUG and see what commands are requested.  However, note that sshd DEBUG logging is a user privacy violation.

If you are trying to do this kind of stuff to find out what is happening on the first "boot" of a docker instance, try putting the (temporarily) config changes into the docker image that you are starting.

---

The bash history only contains command lines that are submitted to the shell via a shell command prompt.

Comment: Hi Stephen C, thank you.  I'm really sorry that I did not mention this piece of important information: What if the targeted ssh host is a new instance to be created?

Comment: *"The remote host is a new docker to be created."* - You cannot ssh to it unless it has already been created.